# Make a ggplot's strip text extend over axis text

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra

Working with ggplot2, I'd like to make a faceted plot where the strip text is centered over both each sub-plot and its y-axis text, rather than centered over just the sub-plot. For reference, here's an example of the plot I'm looking to create:

### Desired Plot

[image]

This is in contrast to the same plot, but where the strip text is centered over just the sub-plot areas, as below.

### Default ggplot2 plot

[image]

For reference, here's the code used to produce this plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

diamonds_plot <- diamonds %>% 
  filter(clarity %in% c("IF", "I1")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = price, y = cut)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ clarity, scales = 'free')
```

How can I make this change programmatically?

I'm guessing that this can be done by editing the layout object obtained from calling `diamonds_plot %>% ggplot_build %>% ggplot_gtable()`, but the exact changes to make are hard to determine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have the right idea.

```
g <- ggplotGrob(diamonds_plot)
g$layout
#     t  l  b  r  z clip        name
# 20  1  1 11 11  0   on  background
# 1   7  4  7  4  1   on   panel-1-1
# 2   7  8  7  8  1   on   panel-2-1
# 3   5  4  5  4  3  off  axis-t-1-1
# 4   5  8  5  8  3  off  axis-t-2-1
# 5   8  4  8  4  3  off  axis-b-1-1
# 6   8  8  8  8  3  off  axis-b-2-1
# 7   7  7  7  7  3  off  axis-l-1-2
# 8   7  3  7  3  3  off  axis-l-1-1
# 9   7  9  7  9  3  off  axis-r-1-2
# 10  7  5  7  5  3  off  axis-r-1-1
# 11  6  4  6  4  2   on strip-t-1-1
# 12  6  8  6  8  2   on strip-t-2-1
# 13  4  4  4  8  4  off      xlab-t
# 14  9  4  9  8  5  off      xlab-b
# 15  7  2  7  2  6  off      ylab-l
# 16  7 10  7 10  7  off      ylab-r
# 17  3  4  3  8  8  off    subtitle
# 18  2  4  2  8  9  off       title
# 19 10  4 10  8 10  off     caption
```

Shift the left edge of the strips:

```
g$layout$l[g$layout$name == "strip-t-1-1"] <- 3
g$layout$l[g$layout$name == "strip-t-2-1"] <- 7
# or more programmatically, with thanks to Mike H.
# g$layout$l[grepl("strip-t", gp$layout$name)] <- g$layout$l[grepl("strip-t", gp$layout$name)] - 1
grid::grid.draw(g)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Or more programmatically: `g$layout$l[grepl("strip-t", gp$layout$name)] <- g$layout$l[grepl("strip-t", gp$layout$name)] - 1`

Comment: What an elegant solution! Do you know if the shift always need to be '-1'?

Comment: @bschneidr the y-axis is one gtable "column" to the left of the plot. `gtable::gtable_show_layout(g)` might help you visualize